# Determine full Moon position into sky from Sun position

Tags: the-moon

Soon a lunar eclipse will take place soon.

I'm not sure if I will be able to see the moon during the eclipse (from 9:30 PM to 11:00 PM), because, I have some building, mountains... in my field of view.

So, I wonder:

On lunar eclipes, will the Moon position at 9:30 PM be the same than the Sun position at 9:30 AM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sun's and Moon's [hour angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hour_angle) at those times will be similar (both about 48$^\circ$ east of the meridian), but their [declinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declination) will be opposite (Sun 19$^\circ$ north of the equator, Moon 19$^\circ$ south).
The Sun in the morning will be over 30$^\circ$ higher than the Moon in the evening.

As the Moon rises and sets about 50 minutes later each day, a better predictor for the Moon's position at 21:30 on July 27 is the Moon's position at 20:40 on July 26, about 1$^\circ$ lower than the eclipse position if observing from a mid-northern latitude.

Answer (score 1):

Visibility of this eclipse will depend on many things.

1 Is the moon visible at your location during the eclipse - your profile shows you live in France, so yes, but the eclipse may have already started at the time of moon rise.

2 What is the weather going to be like -ie will it be clear?

3 Are there local obstructions? To get to your question, where will the moon be at any time?  It will not be where the sun is 12 hours earlier; that would only happen if the eclipse happened on an equinox.
I think your best bet is to download one of the several free sky map programs, eg Stellarium, and set it to your location.  In any event the eclipse will last several hours, so even if you cant see it at first, you may be able to see it later.  Alternatively go out to some other location.